# Chrome Custom Tabs not working

Tags: android, appauth

I am using the tutorial from CodeLabs and in an attempt to test my authorization at [Step 8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#8), I get a log info `06-13 14:15:42.053 3089-3089/com.google.codelabs.appauth I/AppAuth: Unable to bind custom tabs service` and as such I am unable to see if this works. Any help to understand why this is happening and how to solve it will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is Chrome installed on your test device / emulator? If not, that would explain why the custom tabs service cannot bind. However, this should not prevent authorization from working; AppAuth should fall back to using the system browser and still work.

Comment: @iainmcgin you are right. I figured this out later. Can you post in the answer section so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Chrome (or any other browser that supports the custom tab service) is not installed on the device, then this error will be displayed. However, this should not prevent authorization from working - AppAuth will fall back to using the system browser if no custom tab provider is available.

Comment: This also happens if chrome is present but not set as default.